# Getting error in "You have exceeded the maximum transaction amount set by your bank" when calling Paytm or PhonePe by using react-native-upi-payment

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, upi

I am facing this weird problem with my react-native-upi-payment integration in React Native app. When I am sending an amount, I am getting the error "You have exceeded the maximum transaction amount set by your bank" even though I have not transacted any amount. And when I try to send amount directly from Phone pay or Paytm it works.

Payment Transaction is Failed and getting message :

"You have exceeded the maximum transaction amount set by your bank" when calling Paytm or PhonePe or any other UPI App

My Code:

```
  const initPayment = () => {
    try {
      RNUpiPayment.initializePayment(
      {
        vpa: 'testuser@okicici', // or can be john@ybl or mobileNo@upi
        payeeName: 'Test User',
        amount: '1',
        transactionNote: 'Transaction Note',
        transactionRef: 'aasf-332-aoeifn',
      },
      successCallback,
      failureCallback,
     );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


function successCallback(data) {
    try {
      console.log('Success');
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


function failureCallback(data) {
    try {
      console.log('Failed');
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What did your bank say when you asked them about this message?

Comment: I didn't ask the bank, it occurs at every UPI ID that I set as in vpa

Comment: I can't understand its error from my end or bank side issue

Answer (score -1):

This error is from your Bank when your KYC details are not updated. Banks are required to keep records of updated KYC every 2 years. They will send you SMS and a formal letter to provide information on KYC again and if you have missed it, they will freeze your account for all digital transactions.

You may have to visit your bank with PAN/Aadhaar photocopy and fill out the KYC form to get your account unblocked.